# Installing duplicate packages with dependencies R

Tags: r, install.packages

I am using R-studio on a server where I don't have admin status on.

I am able to install some packages, but I need to use a few packages which I am NOT able to install due to the error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was wondering if (and how) I am able to install these packages where I don't have any access on to install locally.

The packages I am interested in: caret, Hmisc and mice.

I already tried to install the packages using devtools::install_github, but that didn't work either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the packages with install.packages() and require()

```
load.packages <- function(x){
  for(i in x){
if(!require(i, character.only = TRUE) ){
  install.packages(i, dependencies = TRUE)
  require(i, character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }
}

load.packages (c("caret", "Hmisc", "mice"))
```

Does it works for you ?

Comment: I am already doing that for all the packages I am able to install. I think (but I am not sure) that the underlying problem is that the packages (for example caret) wants it's dependencies to be updated aswell (like ggplot2, which is in the base installs of the server I am working on, version number 1.0.1). This causes R to try to update ggplot2, which it can't because it is installed and protected in the 'shared libraries folder'.
I want to get around that issue.